# Deploy rdl report to remote server

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I have report solution file with one project and one report.I have designed rdl report using BI in SSDT tools. After creating report successfully build is success and preview is ok. No problem did not arise when i did create report.

Now, I want to deploy this report to my remote reporting server. I gave a url like this www.plumeria.arvixe.com/Reports into Target server url. when i press deploy then need username and password, i gave that. after certain time it appears a errors like this.

[image: Remove server url does not exist]

Many times i have tried but not get a proper solution step by step deploy rdl report to remote server.

Is there any solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"like this www.plumeria.arvixe.com/Reports into Target server url" is not correct. What you are referring to is the Report Manager.

You have to correctly specify:
Target Dataset folder
Target Data Source Folder
Target Report Folder -->From your project
Target Server URL-->Get it from Reporting Services Configuration Manager
Target Server version.

You may need elevvated permissions in SSDT.

My target url used in my book is as follows:

```
http://HODENTEKWIN7/Report_Server_Kailua
```

The instance name of SQL Server is Kailua and it is native mode.

This is a comprehensive book covering SQL Server 2012 both native mode and SharePoint

[image]

Comment: Can you configure my reporting service server.I have not done this. if you agree i will give you my server information.please give me your mail address. if you solve my problem i will give you $10.